# I want to extract a certain number of words surrounding a given word in a long string(paragraph) in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, numbers, extract, words

I am trying to extract a selected number of words surrounding a given word. I will give example to make it clear:

*string = "Education shall be directed to the full development of the human personality and to the strengthening of respect for human rights and fundamental freedoms."*

1) The selected word is **development** and I need to get the 6 words surrounding it, and get : [to, the, full, of, the, human]

---

2) But if the selected word is in the beginning or in second position I still need to get 6 words, e.g:

The selected word is **shall** , I should get: [Education, be, directed, to , the , full]

I should use 're' module. What I managed to find until now is :

```
def search(text,n):
'''Searches for text, and retrieves n words either side of the text, which are retuned seperatly'''
word = r"\W*([\w]+)"
groups = re.search(r'{}\W*{}{}'.format(word*n,'place',word*n), text).groups()
return groups[:n],groups[n:]
```

but it helps me only with the first case. Can someone  help me out with this, I will be really grateful. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Split on spaces and work with the resulting list. No need for regular expressions except maybe to strip punctuation at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will extract all occurrences of the target word in your text, with context:

```
import re

text = ("Education shall be directed to the full development of the human personality "
        "and to the strengthening of respect for human rights and fundamental freedoms.")

def search(target, text, context=6):
    # It's easier to use re.findall to split the string, 
    # as we get rid of the punctuation
    words = re.findall(r'\w+', text)

    matches = (i for (i,w) in enumerate(words) if w.lower() == target)
    for index in matches:
        if index < context //2:
            yield words[0:context+1]
        elif index > len(words) - context//2 - 1:
            yield words[-(context+1):]
        else:
            yield words[index - context//2:index + context//2 + 1]

print(list(search('the', text)))
# [['be', 'directed', 'to', 'the', 'full', 'development', 'of'], 
#  ['full', 'development', 'of', 'the', 'human', 'personality', 'and'], 
#  ['personality', 'and', 'to', 'the', 'strengthening', 'of', 'respect']]

print(list(search('shall', text)))
# [['Education', 'shall', 'be', 'directed', 'to', 'the', 'full']]

print(list(search('freedoms', text)))
# [['respect', 'for', 'human', 'rights', 'and', 'fundamental', 'freedoms']]
```

Comment: That's a nice approach.

Answer (score 1):

Tricky with potential for off-by-one errors but I think this meets your spec. I have left removal of punctuation, probably best to remove it before sending the string for analysis. I assumed case was not important.

```
test_str = "Education shall be directed to the full development of the human personality and to the strengthening of respect for human rights and fundamental freedoms."

def get_surrounding_words(search_word, s, n_words):
    words = s.lower().split(' ')
    try:
        i = words.index(search_word)
    except ValueError:
        return []
    # Word is near start
    if i < n_words/2:
        words.pop(i)
        return words[:n_words]
    # Word is near end
    elif i >= len(words) - n_words/2:
        words.pop(i)
        return words[-n_words:]
    # Word is in middle
    else:
        words.pop(i)
        return words[i-n_words/2:i+n_words/2]

def test(word):
    print('{}: {}'.format(word, get_surrounding_words(word, test_str, 6)))

test('notfound')
test('development')
test('shall')
test('education')
test('fundamental')
test('for')
test('freedoms')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys, os

args = sys.argv[1:]
if len(args) != 2:
   os.exit("Use with <string> <query>")
text = args[0]
query = args[1]
words = text.split()
op = []
left = 3
right = 3
try:
    index = words.index(query)
    if index <= left:
        start = 0
    else:
        start = index - left

    if start + left + right + 1 > len(words):
        start = len(words) - left - right - 1
        if start < 0:
            start = 0

    while len(op) < left + right and start < len(words):
        if start != index:
            op.append(words[start])
        start += 1
except ValueError:
    pass
print op
```

- How do this work?

  1. find the word in the string
  2. See if we can make left+right words from the index the
  3. Take left+right number of words and save them in op
  4. print op

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach to your problem. First separates all the words and then selects words from left and right.

```
def custom_search(sentence, word, n):     
    given_string = sentence
    given_word = word
    total_required = n
    word_list = given_string.strip().split(" ")
    length_of_words = len(word_list)

    output_list = []
    given_word_position = word_list.index(given_word)
    word_from_left = 0
    word_from_right = 0

    if given_word_position + 1 > total_required / 2:
        word_from_left = total_required / 2
        if given_word_position + 1 + (total_required / 2) <= length_of_words:
            word_from_right = total_required / 2
        else:
            word_from_right = length_of_words - (given_word_position + 1)
            remaining_words = (total_required / 2) - word_from_right
            word_from_left += remaining_words

    else:
        word_from_right = total_required / 2
        word_from_left = given_word_position
        if word_from_left + word_from_right < total_required:
            remaining_words = (total_required / 2) - word_from_left
            word_from_right += remaining_words

    required_words = []
    for i in range(given_word_position - word_from_left, word_from_right + 
    given_word_position + 1):
        if i != given_word_position:
            required_words.append(word_list[i])
    return required_words


sentence = "Education shall be directed to the full development of the human personality and to the strengthening of respect for human rights and fundamental freedoms."
custom_search(sentence, "shall", 6)

>>[Education, be, directed, to , the , full] 


custom_search(sentence, "development", 6)

>>['to', 'the', 'full', 'of', 'the', 'human']
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think regular expressions are necessary here. Assuming the text is well-constructed, just split it up into an array of words, and write a couple if-else statements to make sure it retrieves the necessary amount of surrounding words:

```
def search(text, word, n):
    # text is the string you are searching
    # word is the word you are looking for
    # n is the TOTAL number of words you want surrounding the word

    words    = text.split(" ")  # Create an array of words from the string
    position = words.index(word)   # Find the position of the desired word

    distance_from_end = len(words) - position  # How many words are after the word in the text

    if position < n // 2 + n % 2:  # If there aren't enough words before...
        return words[:position], words[position + 1:n + 1]

    elif distance_from_end < n // 2 + n % 2:  # If there aren't enough words after...
        return words[position - n + distance_from_end:position], words[position + 1:]

    else:  # Otherwise, extract an equal number of words from both sides (take from the right if odd)
        return words[position - n // 2 - n % 2:position], words[position + 1:position + 1 + n//2]

string = "Education shall be directed to the full development of the human personality and to the \
strengthening of respect for human rights and fundamental freedoms."

print search(string, "shall", 6)
# >> (['Education'], ['be', 'directed', 'to', 'the', 'full'])

print search(string, "human", 5)
# >> (['development', 'of', 'the'], ['personality', 'and'])
```

In your example you didn't have the target word included in the output, so I kept it out as well. If you'd like the target word included simply combine the two arrays the function returns (join them at `position`).

Hope this helped!