# Spark regex with non-capturing group before and after matches not working as expected

Tags: java, regex, apache-spark, pyspark

I have been breaking my head trying to make this regex work. After much googling and consultation with colleagues, it's still not working as expected.

I have a set of target words (see example of terms in the comment line) that I want to capture, along with the surrounding 3 words to form a snippet string. Below is a function that does so for a string in a PySpark dataframe:

```
def extract_snippet(df, text_col):

    e = ["rt", "lt", "bi"]
    before = r"(?:\S+\s+){0,3}"
    after = r"\s*(?:\S+\b\s*){0,3}"

    for eye in e:
        if eye == "rt":
            # terms: right, od, rt, r eye, r_eye
            p = before + r"\b[oO]{1}[dD]{1}\b|\b[rR]{1}(?:igh|IGH)?[tT]{1}\b|\b[rR]{1}[^a-zA-Z0-9]{0,4}eye{1}\b" + after
        elif eye == "lt":
            # terms: left, os, lt, l eye, l_eye
            p = before + r"\b[oO]{1}[sS]{1}\b|\b[lL]{1}(?:ef|EF)?[tT]{1}\b|\b[lL]{1}[^a-zA-Z0-9]{0,4}eye{1}\b" + after
        else:
            # ou, bi, bilat, bilateral, both
            p = before + r"\b[oO]{1}[uU]{1}\b|\b(?:bi|BI|Bi){1}(?:lat|LAT|LATERAL|lateral)?\b|\b(?:both|BOTH|Both){1}\b" + after

        snippet_udf = udf(lambda s: re.findall(p, s), ArrayType(StringType()))
        df = df.withColumn(eye + "_snippet", snippet_udf(col(text_col)))

    return df
```

I need to keep the expression broken in pieces because "p" will change depending on the target terms

Here are some examples:

#### example 1:

`Type 2 diabetes mellitus with moderate nonproliferative diabetic retinopathy with macular edema, left eye  Care Plan:`

What I expect it to return:

`'with macular edema, left eye  Care Plan'`

What I'm getting:

`'left'`

#### example 2:

`Primary open-angle glaucoma, moderate stage  Comments       :  IOP STILL ELEVATED OD Visual Field and ONA reviewed with patient`

What I expect it to return:

`'IOP STILL ELEVATED OD Visual Field and '`

What I'm getting:

`'IOP STILL ELEVATED OD'`

These examples work as expected (full match) in the regex tester [here](https://regex101.com/r/8WZXiM/2/), but not when I apply it to transform a string in a Spark dataframe column.

**For some strings like in example 2, the regex seems to work to capture the words before, but not after the target word** (I'm aware that .findall() will only return non-overlapping words, this is not the problem).

I've tried Java regex testers instead of a Python tester like the one in the link but I got the same (correct) output, so I'm lost.

In Presto, this works perfectly:

```
SELECT regexp_extract_all(col_name, '((?:\S+\s+){0,3}(\b[oO]{1}[sS]{1}\b|\b[lL]{1}(ef|EF)?[tT]{1}\b|\b[lL]{1}[^a-zA-Z0-9]{0,4}eye{1}\b)\s*(?:\S+\b\s*){0,3})') FROM ...
```

The difference among the regex in the pySpark snippet, in the regex tester, and the Presto query is **where parentheses go**. I've played with it though and it hasn't yet solved the problem...

#### EDIT: I've added the entire function as well as another example

Comment: The regex tester linked captures just left when using javascript, it times out for python

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43449773/i-want-to-extract-a-certain-number-of-words-surrounding-a-given-word-in-a-long-s

Comment: @sramalingam24 I'm interested in the full match. I updated the link to reflect the full match as a group. I'm not sure why it times out, I did not have that problem.

Comment: @Prazy that is a cool idea, I had thought of something similar (tokenization then extract adjacent strings), but I was hoping fixing the regex would be a simpler solution that I could integrate into an existing function rather than creating a new one. I will resort to this idea in case no one can help with the regex.

Comment: What does this have to do with Java?

Comment: Spark runs on the JVM. I have not checked how a Python regex is compiled for Spark, but Presto, for example, compiles to Java regex